# Left-aligning text within a wpf button at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a Button at runtime with a ViewBox and inside the ViewBox I'm adding a TextBlock. It all works fine, except I can't seem to get the text to left-align. After some fiddling, I realized this is because the TextBlock isn't the full width of the button.

```
var row = new RowDefinition();
OrdersGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);

var button = new Button();
button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
button.MaxHeight = 40;
button.Background = (Brush)System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources["OrangeGradient"];
button.BorderThickness = new Thickness(.1);
button.Margin = new Thickness(.1);

OrdersGrid.Children.Add(button);
Grid.SetColumn(button, 0);
Grid.SetRow(button, rowNumber);

Viewbox vb = new Viewbox();
vb.StretchDirection = StretchDirection.Both;
vb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
tb.Text = rowNumber  + " - " + CustomerName;
tb.Padding = new Thickness(0);
tb.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;

vb.Child = tb;
button.Content = vb;
```

If I change `tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;` to `tb.Width = 400;` it left-aligns. However, I have no guarantee that that is the correct size, but it does narrow the problem down to the width of the TextBlock. How can I make the TextBlock (And ViewBox) the full width of the Button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property of the `Button` to `Left`:

```
button.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to make the contents the full width of the button? What visual or functional difference would that make? I don't see anything in your code that would require that. If the TextBlock had a background brush of its own, that would be a reason, but it doesn't.

If you absolutely did need to left center the text within something stretched, put a `Border` around the ViewBox inside the button, set Button.HorizontalContentAlignment = Stretch, and set ViewBox.HorizontalAlignment = Left.

The bottom line here is that the Button's content is by default centered in the Button's content area, and `Button.HorizontalContentAlignment` controls that. Its default value is Center. If you want to force the content to stretch, set it to Stretch.

If you really just want to left justify the content, just use mm8's answer. Quick and easy.